# How to convert images with ImageMagick convert to make "standard" JPEGs?

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

I have lots of images in various formats. I want to convert them to JPEG with same parameters (standardized). I thought it would be enough to just do:

```
convert image.ext -strip image.jpg
```

But some of them are greyscale 8bit, some are 24 bit RGB, some are 32 bit CMYK. Their dpi also varies. I don't even know what other parameters might be different. I want them all to have exact same parameters except height & width. With no metadata.
I currently have this:

```
convert -colorspace sRGB -units PixelsPerInch  image.ext -density 72 -strip image.jpg
```

What else should I add?

Comment: btw, forget 'dpi', it's a red herring. An image on a computer has no DPI it only has dimensions in pixels.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but I know that. But some programs use dpi information to rescale images. Wanna but sure they are not rescaled.